# Changing Col. Width in tabularx environment and difficulty making table appear where I want

Tags: positioning, tabularx, column-width

I am trying to widen the column titled "application" so the table overall is less tall, and I also have been experiencing trouble changing where the table appears (now it always appears at the next page) despite putting parameters like h, t, b, ! next to the {table*} command. Here is the code below:

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt}
\begin{table*}[h!]
 \caption{COMPARISON OF SUITABILITY OF SELECT ESS TO PROVIDE SHORT TERM GRID FUNCTIONS}
\label{my-label}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{20}{C}c@{}}
\toprule
\multirow{Service Category}    & \multirow{Application} & \multirow{Discharge Duration} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Energy Storage System} \\
[-\normalbaselineskip]
\cmidrule{4-8} 
{} & {} & {} & Sodium-sulfur Battery & Lithium-ion Battery & Flywheel & SMES  & Supercapacitors \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{Generation} & Inertia Provision\tnote{1} & \textless10s & - & - & + & + & + \\ 
& Primary and Fast Frequency Response\tnote{2} & up to 30s & - & - & + & + & + \\ 
& Frequency Regulation & up to 15-20 minutes & + & + & + & + & + \\ 
& Contingency Reserves & up to 1 hour & - & + & - & - & - \\
& Ramping & minutes to hours & - & + & - & - & - \\
& Voltage Support & 15 minutes to 1 hour & + & + & + & + & +\\
& Renewable Grid Integration(short duration) & 10 seconds to 15 minutes & - & + & + & + & + \\
Transmission/Distribution & Transmission Support & 2-5 seconds & - & - & + & + & + \\
\multirow{End-user} & Power Quality Support & 10 seconds to 1 minute & + & - &  + & + & + \\
& Uninterruptible Power Supply & seconds to hours & - & + & + & + & + \\
Resilience & Backup power \& Outage Ride Through & 5 minutes to 1 hour & + & - & - & + & - \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
     \item[1] Proposed
     \item[2] Proposed
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable} 
\end{table*}
```

This is how the table looks right now

[image: How the image looks right now]

Would appreciate all help!

Comment: table* only supports [t] and [p], and never appears on the same page it is created on.  There are alternatives, but they involve things like \afterpage or \twocolumn[...] which also start on the next page.

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. How is the C column type defined?

Comment: To improve the table I'd allow linebreaks inside of the first column, use abbreviated column headers in order to save space, e.g. "Li-ion" instead of "lithium ion", and abbreviated units in the third column, e. g. "h" instead of "hours" with these changes you should be able to save enough space to make your second column wider.

Answer (score 1):

See if the following table design is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[h!]
 \caption{Comparison of suitability of select ess to provide short term grid functions}
\label{my-label}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L{1} L{1.6} L{0.8} *{6}{C{0.6}} @{}}
    \toprule
\multirow{3}{=}{Service Category}    
    & \multirow{3}{=}{Application} 
        & \multirow{3}{=}{Discharge Duration} 
            & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Energy Storage System} \\
\cmidrule{4-8}
    &   &   & \ce{Na}-\ce{S} Battery\tnote{[a]}
                & \ce{Li}-ion Battery\tnote{[b]} 
                    & Flywheel 
                        & SMES  
                            & Super C\tnote{[c]}                  \\
\midrule
\multirow[t]{3}{=}{Generation} 
    & Inertia Provision\tnote{1} 
        & \SI{<10}{s}               & - & - & + & + & + \\
    & Primary and Fast Frequency Response\tnote{2} 
        & up to \SI{30}{s}          & - & - & + & + & + \\
    & Frequency Regulation 
        & \SIrange{15}{20}{min}       
                                    & + & + & + & + & + \\
    & Contingency Reserves          
        & up to \SI{1}{h}           & - & + & - & - & - \\
    & Ramping 
        & minutes to hours          & - & + & - & - & - \\
    & Voltage Support 
        & \SIrange{15}{60}{min}     & + & + & + & + & + \\
    & Renewable Grid Integration (short duration) 
        & \SI{10}{s} to \SI{15}{min}& - & + & + & + & + \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow[t]{2}{=}{Transmission/ Distribution}
    & Transmission Support 
        & \SIrange{2}{5}{s}         & - & - & + & + & + \\
    &   &                           &   &   &   &   &   \\
\multirow[t]{3}{=}{End-user} 
    & Power Quality Support 
        & 10 seconds to 1 minute    & + & - & + & + & + \\
    & Uninterruptible Power Supply 
        & seconds to hours          & - & + & + & + & + \\
Resilience 
    & Backup power \& Outage Ride Through 
        & \SIrange{5}{60}{min}      & + & - & - & + & - \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para]
     \item[{[a]}] Sodium–sulfur battery
     \item[{[b]}] Lithium-ion battery 
     \item[{[c]}] Supercapacitors\par
     \item[1] Proposed
     \item[2] Proposed
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]